# How Do I add a 'Game Over' screen to my Unity game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a total begginer in Unity and making a simple catch game (falling fruits and a basket). I have the 'Game Over' screen design ready - it contains the Game Over text, score info and a restart button. But I don't know how and where do I reference it in my code after the game ends. I am aware that I need a GameManager script but it is currently empty because I don't know how to write the function.

I'm assuming that I need to call the function in my score system script, where I'm telling the program to restart after the player catches a bomb.
This is that portion of the code.

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text scoreText;
    int score = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target)
    {
        if (target.tag == "tomato")
        StartCoroutine(WaitTillRestart());

        else if (target.tag == "bag")
        {
            score++;
            Destroy(target.gameObject);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitTillRestart ()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can either add a text "Game Over" to your current scene, or have a new scene entirely

Answer (score 1):

Simple Game Over panel show Script!
if you want to stop your game time when Game over. use Time.timescale = 0f. //0 <- stop 1 <- resume

```
    public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject _GameOverPanel; // <- add this. Then drag and drop your game over panel onto the inspector.
    public TMP_Text scoreText;
    int score = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target)
    {
        if (target.tag == "tomato")
        StartCoroutine(WaitTillRestart());

        else if (target.tag == "bag")
        {
            score++;
            Destroy(target.gameObject);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitTillRestart ()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        GameOver(); // <- add func
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }

    void GameOver()
   {
    Time.timeScale = 0f; // <- It will stop your game time. use it if you need it.
    _GameOverPanel.Setactive(true); // <- Show GameOver Panel
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a canvas in the editor containing the "Game Over" text and button and hide it initially. Then from your Score script, use the UnityEngine.UI namespace and create an instance of the canvas by declaring a [Serializefield] Canvas variable and dragging the canvas object from the hierarchy in the editor. Write a line to set the visibility of the GameOver canvas to true in the loss condition before the restarting Coroutine.

```
GetComponent<Canvas>().gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

It is preferable to stop the ability of the user to move the character or interact with the game while the "Game Over" canvas is active, thus I recommend sending a message to the interaction script calling a function that stops that. This can be done by having a boolean that is true by default as a condition for interaction and having a function to set it to true or false.

This way I believe there would be no need for a GameManager script.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a gameobject under canvas that contains your "game over screen" (advise: have a sprite that is flexed to whole screen in that object with color value `(0, 0, 0, 0.7)`) than run a `GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform.Find("Game Over").SetActive(true);` extra advise: Have `Time.timescale=0` for animations etc. to stop